# AxiosError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: javascript, ssl, axios

I'm trying to get request from API using Axios, but it always returns the error like below.

```
node_modules/axios/dist/node/axios.cjs:837
  AxiosError.call(axiosError, error.message, code, config, request, response);
             ^
AxiosError: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
  {
  localAddress: undefined,
  port: 443,
  host: 'hocbadientu.vnedu.vn',
  path: null,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  config: {
    transitional: {
      silentJSONParsing: true,
      forcedJSONParsing: true,
      clarifyTimeoutError: false
    },
    adapter: [ 'xhr', 'http' ],
    transformRequest: [ [Function: transformRequest] ],
    transformResponse: [ [Function: transformResponse] ],
    timeout: 0,
    xsrfCookieName: 'XSRF-TOKEN',
    xsrfHeaderName: 'X-XSRF-TOKEN',
    maxContentLength: -1,
    maxBodyLength: -1,
    env: {
      FormData: [Function: FormData] {
        LINE_BREAK: '\r\n',
        DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE: 'application/octet-stream'
      },
      Blob: [class Blob]
    },
    validateStatus: [Function: validateStatus],
    headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] {
      Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
      'Content-Type': undefined,
      'User-Agent': 'axios/1.6.0',
      'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, compress, deflate, br'
    },
    params: {
      call: 'solienlac.checkSll',
      mahocsinh: 'xxx',
      password: 'xxx',
      tinh_id: 'x',
      namhoc: 'xx',
      dot_diem_id: 0
    },
    method: 'get',
    url: 'https://hocbadientu.vnedu.vn/sllservices/index.php',
    data: undefined
  },
  cause: Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
      at connResetException (node:internal/errors:711:14)
      at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (node:_tls_wrap:1593:19)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:525:35)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:domain:489:12)
      at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1359:12) {
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    path: null,
    host: 'hocbadientu.vnedu.vn',
    port: 443,
    localAddress: undefined
  }
}

Node.js v18.12.1
```

and here is my code

```js
let pass = await axios.get(`https://hocbadientu.vnedu.vn/sllservices/index.php`, {
    params: {
      call: 'solienlac.checkSll',
      mahocsinh: `${E.PI}`,
      password: `${E.PN}`,
      tinh_id: '42',
      namhoc: `${year}`,
      dot_diem_id: 0
    }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => { console.log(data) });
```

If I go to that URL, it still returns the correct data. But when I use Axios to get, it returns error. Is that because Axios or API URL ? 
I also tried some ways on the Internet but it also not worked, it also error code `ECONNRESET`. 
But if I use ajax to get the request, it worked!

```js
$.ajax({
    url: 'https://hocbadientu.vnedu.vn/sllservices/index.php',
    jsonp: 'callback',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      ...params
    },
    timeout: 500000,
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
  });
```

Is that any ways to convert this ajax code into axios?
Please help me, thanks!